# TCP server/client connection issue C#

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

so I am currently programming a simple server/client to play some basic games i did in the past.

The problem is that I can only connect while I'm on the same computer, and not via LAN (as I would want it to work), here's the code I'm working with:

Server:
`IPEndPoint Ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
            listener = new TcpListener(Ep);
            listener.Start();`

Client:
`IPAddress direc = IPAddress.Parse(ipManager);
            Ep = new IPEndPoint(direc, 8000);`

The problem is that when I try connect from another computer (connected to the same Wi-Fi obviously) I get the following error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.0.5:8000

I shuold also add that this is the code when I try to connect:

Sever:
`TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();`

Client:
`client.Connect(Ep);`

Apparently when I am connecting the server never "accepts" the connection, but I haven't been able to figure out why's that.

Comment: What language are you using? C++? What platform is this, windows or linux?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that! It's C#, Visual Studio. I'm working on WPF

Comment: Have you added a exception to windows firewall? Try disabling it for a test and try to connect again, check if it works.

Comment: Firewall is off on both computers, any other ideas ? :S

Comment: Can you ping your two machines back and forth? It might be your WiFi router blocking point 2 point connections in your WAN. If ping is not working then the problem is not with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it works locally, you are probably using `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` as the server's listening interface. Try using `0.0.0.0` so it will listen on all interfaces or specify the IP address of the interface you want the server to listen on.

Comment: I'm using 0.0.0.0, still nothing :/

Comment: Did you try something like this? `new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 8000)`

Comment: Do you have any sort of packet sniffing software (eg. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) available at the server computer? If you do you can try connecting and checking out if the client packets are actually arriving at the specified server interface (192.168.0.5).

Comment: Try running your server and then issuing this command on a DOS prompt: `netstat -a | find "LISTENING"`. If the server is working right it should show port 8000 as listening.

Comment: It appears: TCP 0.0.0.0:8000 LISTENING

Comment: When I try to connect from the Client to the Server the endpoint should be 192.168.0.5:8000, right? (The Server is in 192.168.0.5 and the client in 192.168.0.9).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13392/discussion-between-claudio-and-waclock)

Comment: In case anyone has this problem: My problem was the ANTIVIRUS' FIREWALL, which I forgot to check. It might be dumb, but it happens! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect to the port using telnet or netcat. Check if the port is accessible.

```
$ nc 192.168.0.5 8000
$ telnet 192.168.0.5 8000
```

Comment: How do I use that? Sorry for the ignorance :P

Comment: You must run the program and see what happened. Either you will get message that the port is closed (or nothing in case of `nc` variant), or you will get a connection.

Comment: It's C#, that's not C# is it?

Comment: @waclock, these are linux programs. Since now you said you are programming in C# you're probably on Windows and so you won't have them. Telnet you might have though, the idea is just to try to connect to your server port to see if it is listening.

Comment: http://www.labnol.org/software/windows-telnet-command/18222/
Here you can have telenet for windows.
Have you tried simply pinging the server? (possible from windows command line)